# Jquery get attr of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, get

Hi there i have this code structure:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);">
        <a href="/anyHref_1">list_1</a>
    </li>
    <li style="background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);">
        <a href="/anyHref_2">list_2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the href from the "a" which is the child-element of the list with the background-color:rgb(100, 100, 100) , so:

```
var test = $('ul#list li[style~="backgroundColor: rgb(100, 100, 100)"] > a').attr('href');
```

But test is undefined :/ Anybody could tell me what am i doing wrong? Thanks!! and greets:)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x96Je/3/

you can try this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)? That would return all `li`s with a background of `rgb(100,100,100)`:

```
$("li").filter(function() {
   return $(this).css("background-color") === "rgb(100, 100, 100)";
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4gGG2/)

To grab the href of a single link:

```
var href = $("li").filter(function() {
   return $(this).css("background-color") === "rgb(100, 100, 100)" 
}).find("a").prop("href");
```

The reason I'd go for this approach is because it doesn't rely on the style attribute, which may not be typed in the way you expect.

Comment: Just add `.find("a").prop("href")` to the end :) @user3683881 Updated answer

Comment: What if my browser uses RGBA, then css() would return a RGBA value instead ?

Comment: @adeneo Not if it wasn't set as an `rgba()` value. At least the latest version of Chrome doesn't for me...

Comment: @RGraham - The latest version of chrome doesn't do that for me either, but it used to be an issue, just not sure in what browser/version ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your selector. It should be background-color

```
$('ul#list li[style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);"] > a').attr("href")
```

instead of backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

You must use *= and change backgroundColor as background-color

```
var test = $('ul#list li[style*="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100)"] > a').attr('href');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x96Je/1/